# QLThumbnailGenerator cannot generate thumbnail when the pdf file is large

Tags: swift

```swift
let generator = QLThumbnailGenerator.shared
Task {
    do {
        let generated = try await generator.generateBestRepresentation(for: request)
        print(generated)   // <----- cannot get this when the file is large.
    }
    catch let err {
        print(err)
    }
}
```

I'm trying to create thumbnails for some pdf files. Everything works perfectly with small pdf files. But I cannot get the thumbnail for the large pdfs (e.g., > 10M).

Is there any file size limitation of QLThumbnailGenerator?

Thanks!

Comment: @matt Thanks for your reply. I use `let request = QLThumbnailGenerator.Request(fileAt: url!, size: size, scale: (NSScreen.main?.backingScaleFactor)!, representationTypes: .thumbnail)` to create the request, and use QLThumbnailGenerator.shared to generate the thumbnail. How to avoid QLThumbnailGenerator.shared? Could you please write some demo code? I'm a beginner of macOS development. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a limitation of the `async` version of `generateBestRepresentation`. Try instead calling

```
generateRepresentations(
    for request: QLThumbnailGenerator.Request, 
    update updateHandler: ((QLThumbnailRepresentation?, QLThumbnailRepresentation.RepresentationType, Error?) -> Void)? = nil
)
```

This will make multiple callbacks to `updateHandler` and you can keep checking the representation type until you get the `.thumbnail`, or you can just stop when you get the first `.lowQualityThumbnail` if you like.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply, I've tried your code.

For small pdfs, I will get the icon first and the thumbnail is following.

But for large pdfs, I can also get the icon, but no thumbnail, the error is:
`Error Domain=QLThumbnailErrorDomain Code=2 "No cached thumbnail"`

Comment: Right, well this is only a thumbnail, and giving you the icon because the PDF is too large is expected behavior. A thumbnail _is_ just an icon, after all.

Comment: I also find that I can get the thumbnail for the large file on the M1 MBP, but it's not ok on my MBP17.

Comment: Interesting but again not surprising. You just need to be flexible about this.

Comment: So, it means that my old MBP cannot handle large file, the final thumbnail is just the icon, right?

Comment: Right, for purposes of this API at least.